# GREATER THAN filter not working in WHERE clause using MySQL.EXE (Command line)

Tags: mysql

**EDIT: 12-APR-18 - Changed title with actual source of issue**

I thought it was related to how the datetime value was parsed in the command prompt, but it was an escaping error that required a ^ in the string. **See my answer below**

**/EDIT:**

I think I have an issue with my mysql.exe session and how it is interpreting datetime values, would love some input.

I am unable to filter records on a datetime column when my SQL query is sent to the server via the command line, I'm using mysql.exe.

The filters work for other values such as signed numbers, but not on my datetime column. It always returns from the first records.

If I use the SQL portion of the command in MySQL workbench the query works as expected.
Do I need to set some kind of date format prior to running the query?
I have tried CAST, CONVERT, STR_TO_DATE and explicit strings 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' and none of them work. The following are two examples:

**Works in SQL Workbench**

```
Set @TEST = STR_TO_DATE('2018-01-01 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %T');
SELECT al.db_id,al.created,al.asset_id,al.log_id,CAST(al.latitude/1000000 AS DECIMAL(8,6)),CAST(al.longitude/1000000 AS DECIMAL(9,6)),BIN(al.IO8) 
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/Export_AssetLogs_Cust-83_Grp-189_From-20180101_Created-110418-1657.CSV' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
FROM asset_log as al 
WHERE al.created > @TEST LIMIT 100;
```

**Fails using MySQL.EXE**

```
 mysql -h "127.0.0.1" -u <USER> -p<PASSWORD> -e "Set @TEST = STR_TO_DATE('2018-01-01 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %T');SELECT al.db_id,al.created,al.asset_id,al.log_id,CAST(al.latitude/1000000 AS DECIMAL(8,6)),CAST(al.longitude/1000000 AS DECIMAL(9,6)),BIN(al.IO8) INTO OUTFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/Export_AssetLogs_Cust-83_Grp-189_From-20180101_Created-110418-1657.CSV' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' FROM asset_log as al WHERE al.created > @TEST LIMIT 100;"
```

Also tried variations of escaping the single and double quotes in case I'm doing something wrong in the command line. I'm sure it is something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I walked away after asking this question and I started looking closer at the query today. It was then that I realised the GREATER THAN > symbol is a special character in the WINDOWS COMMAND PROMPT and so it was not making it into the query and hence the date range filter was failing. To overcome the issue I just needed to escape > with ^ so the filter for the date became:

**Escaped Greater Than, works**

```
al.created ^> @TEST
```

**Rather than:**

```
al.created > @TEST
```

This query was taken from a PowerShell script that dynamically created the SQL and command prompt execution logic to run mysql.exe. I didn't realise I needed to include DOS escape characters throughout, but it is pretty obvious now . Hope this helps others.